# How do I create a simple javascript server?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a server where if I pressed "w", a variable (lets say me1) would equal to 1. And if another user (from a different browser and IP) pressed the same key, another variable (lets say other2) would equal to 1.

I don't need everything to be JavaScript (as long as it's easy to understand), I just need the end variables to be JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript server? You want a script that responses with your desired logic, right? Any server-side scripting language will serve your needs. But what have you tried? Why server-side?

Comment: To be clear, are these variables `me1 , other2, ...` shared between these different IP's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your users from different IP's need to be able to talk to each other?

You could use [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) as one way to do this. I only recommend Node because its very simple to setup [sockets](http://socket.io/) if your answer to my above question is yes.

However both technologies would require a medium to advanced skill set.